# Get the ranking of highest score with earliest timestamp

Tags: linq

I have the following records:

```
   name   score Date
   Billy  32470 12/18/2010 7:26:35 PM
   Sally  1100  12/19/2010 12:00:00 AM
   Kitty  1111  12/21/2010 12:00:00 AM
   Sally  330   12/21/2010 8:23:34 PM
   Daisy  32460 12/22/2010 3:10:09 PM
   Sally  32460 12/23/2010 4:51:11 PM
   Kitty  32440 12/24/2010 12:00:27 PM
   Billy  32460 12/24/2010 12:11:36 PM
```

I want to get the leaderboard of the highest score with earliest time stamp using LINQ.
In this case, the correct one is

```
rank name 
  1  Billy 
  2  Daisy 
  3  Sally
```

I use the following query:

```
var result = 
(from s in Submissions
group s by s.name into g
orderby g.Max(q => q.Score) descending,g.Min(q => q.Date) ascending
select new ScoreRecord
{
name = g.Key
Score = g.Max(q => q.Score)
}).Take(3).ToList();
```

I get the following wrong result:

```
rank name 
  1  Billy 
  2  Sally
  3  Daisy
```

What's the correct linq query in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you're getting the max score and the min date for a person but not necessarily the same record.

You need to restrict the min date to only look at those records that have the required max score... this isn't the cleanest way to do it but will work (I'm not good at Linq syntax, much prefer lambda)

```
var result =  
(from s in Submissions 
group s by s.name into g 
orderby g.Max(q => q.Score) descending, 
    g.Where(i => i.Score == g.Max(q => q.Score)).Min(q => q.Date) ascending 
select new ScoreRecord 
{ 
name = g.Key 
Score = g.Max(q => q.Score) 
}).Take(3).ToList();
```

Comment: To tidy it up you could use a `let` statement to put the max score into a variable and reuse that.

Answer (score -1):

try something simple perhaps

```
var max = Submissions.Max(m => m.score);
var result = Submissions.Where(s => s.score == max).OrderBy(s => s.Date);
```